# Raspberry Pi zero bluetooth max transfer speed

Tags: pi-3, bluetooth, pi-zero-w, data-transfer

What is the maximum theoretical limit for bluetooth transfer rate from a raspberry pi zero W to Raspberry pi 3 using RFCOMM?

They both have bluetooth 4.1, which, on wikipedia saids can reach speeds of 25Mbps (bits per second).

Ive only managed to reach 0.3 Mbps, which I measured by sending some bytes from the pi zero to a raspberry pi 3 using the python package PyBluez.

Comment: Can you describe your tests, such as the filesize and commands used for transfer?

Comment: As implied in Miz's answer, bluetooth 4.1 *does not* work at speed anywhere close to 25 Mbps, nor does wikipedia claim that.  I think if you look around you'll find it is more like **1 Mbps** (or less), making your results expectable.

Answer (score 3):

Bluetooth 4 does not have the same speed capacities as bluetooth 3 + HS.
The high speeds were deprecated after bluetooth 3. 
[As written on this article.](https://techspirited.com/bluetooth4-vs-bluetooth3hs)